# What causes Windows 8 Consumer Preview to lock-up / freeze / hang in Oracle VM VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8-preview

I've installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview to a virtual machine using Oracle VM VirtualBox (4.1.14). It works well except for occasional temporary lock-up / freeze / hang interruptions.

It will freeze for about a minute and then resume like normal for several more minutes before freezing again.

**Host**
Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
16 GB RAM
Intel Core i7 (quad core, hyper threading, virtualization) CPU

**Guest**
Windows 8 Consumer Preview 64-bit
2 GB RAM
2 CPUs

How should I configure VirtualBox to run Windows 8 well?

[image: Windows 8 on VirtualBox]

Comment: Maybe because W8cp is BETA software? Developer preview ran better than consumer did for me in VB. Gave up using it in VB and installed it on a spare pc.

Answer (score 1):

It appears, in my case, to only do it when the Virtual Box Additions are installed. I have it installed now without the additions and it is fine. Once I put the additions on, it starts freezing.

I also noticed it froze more in the Start screen when using Metro than it did when I was on the desktop.

EDIT:

I just disabled 3D acceleration in the VB settings for the Win8 guest, and that stopped the freezing. I had noticed some weird video artifacts anyway. My guess is the release preview is doing something in video the consumer preview was not doing, and the VB display drivers don't like it so much.

Unfortunately, you may not get the resolution and video acceleration you want by doing the above. I have a 1920x1080 monitor, but the best I can get is 1280x1024 in fullscreen. Oh well.

Comment: If you install the tools and suffer from slowness, try assigning more cores for the VM. I [had the same problem](http://superuser.com/q/431981/118798).

Comment: I added 4 cores (I have an i7 Sandy Bridge), and that also seem to do the job. I only had 1. I can try two I suppose and see if that's enough, but 4 doesn't seem to bog my system down any. Still I occasionally get some weird blinking from the video. Could be my video card drivers.