# Windows 8 Start Screen very slow after Guest Additions

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8-preview

I installed Windows 8 Release Preview on a VirtualBox VM, and it worked correctly. Then I installed the Guest Additions to get the correct resolutions.

Now, the Start screen is **very slow**, takes a long time to scroll and doesn't respond well to clicks.

I believe it's not my host, as it's a good machine (i7 CPU, 6 GB of RAM) and this specifically starts to happen after installing the Guest Additions.

The task manager doesn't show anything wrong (i.e. no processes pegging the CPU). Any suggestions?

Comment: It's even worse with the RTM version.  I suggest anyone who wants VirtualBox running Win8 RTM wait until they announce that VirtualBox actually runs Windows 8. Right now, it crawls so slowly and thrashes the host machine badly, that the minor problems in Release Preview seem like nothing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue. Assigning more CPU cores (I went up to 4) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

Turning on "use host I/O cache" in storage fixed it for me.

Comment: Any idea what might have caused this?

Comment: Mine was already turned on by default when I created the new VM.

Comment: @MattSlay on my vm it was on for the IDE controller but *not* for the SATA.

Answer (score 0):

Running on two cores, 4gb memory and PXE turned on. It quickly showed the slowness you describe. Going from one to two and PXE allowed it to function normally.

Careful what you install on it, it quickly loses its apps to oddball conflicts.

Once that happens, go over into the sidebar in general configurations. Somewhere there, there's an iPad style restore that blows everything except your data files away. Have your install ISO available to mount as a CD.

Comment: I installed this on a serious machine and it still happened. I suspect a driver in the VirtualBox setup.

Comment: I would imagine we have a few more VirtualBox upgrades before Windows 8 is fully stable on it. Windows 8's got some weird quirkiness that tells me I don't want it on any hardware I depend on. It's still in that kind of alpha-beta stage yet.